# How to write a Resilience4j CircuitBreaker wrapper around rest calls

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I have many services and each of these services call many different remote endpoints, using a base service i.e. service1 ->base_service->endpoint1,2,5, service2 ->base_service->endpoint2,3,5
and so on. 
Base service uses Spring WebClient to make http calls.

Now, I need to crate a configurable circuit breaker wrapper to wrap all of these calls.
I am totally clueless about this but I am aware of circuit breaker pattern. Can you please guide me in the right direction?.

Comment: Were you able to write wrapper on resilience4j? I'm looking wrapper for different use case. I would like to not merge the circuit breaker logic with business logic. Looking for some config class that can be initied at the time of boot and do not touch any existing code to introduce CB.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can apply circuit breaker configuration:

1. [Using resilience4j spring boot integration](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3)
2. [Using reactor integration](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/examples-1)